# Pytorch - multiple GPUs

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, pytorch

I have a rather large network that requires lots of GPU memory. I have 4 GPUs and I use `nn.DataParallel`. When I define a batch size of 4 (1 input for each GPU) my GPUs run out of memory. I tried `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` and removing any unnecessary data from the GPUs, but it was not enough.

I am looking for a way to treat the 4 GPUs as 2 GPUs with double memory, so that I could use a batch size of 2 (1 input for two GPUs). Is there any way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should look into  [horovod](https://github.com/horovod/horovod). it works with pytorch as well as tf.

Comment: are you working with 32bit floating point? have you tried mixed precision - reducing some of the tensors to 16 bit floating point? You should look into [apex](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex) and their [amp](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex#1-amp--automatic-mixed-precision) section.

Comment: Never heard of mixed precision. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use apex because it requires python 3. My model consists of two networks, one of which requires python 2.7.

Comment: how difficult it is to convert to python-3.x?

Comment: [One of the networks](https://github.com/JiaxiongQ/DeepLiDAR). I can't do it in a reasonable time.